# Como passar informação escolhida na combobox para a base de dados?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, combobox

Tenho uma base de dados que é preenchida com dados vindos da base de dados e queria que após carregar no botão, essa informação escolhida fosse para a base de dados.
Sempre que tento enviar os dados que tenho nas textbox sem utilizar a combobox funciona, a partir do momento em uso a combobox já não dá. Tentei enviar o valor da combobox para uma textbox e apartir daí gravar, mas também não consegui que funcionasse.

Este é o código chamado, à página principal:

```
....
if (isset($_POST['botao_marcar']))
{

     $data = trim($_POST['data_marcacao']); 
     $hora = trim($_POST['hora_marcacao']);
     $especialidade= trim($_POST['cbEspecialidade']);
     $observacoes= trim($_POST['observacoes']);


     $sql = "INSERT INTO Consulta_marcada (data, hora_inicio, especialidade observacoes) VALUES ('".$data."', '".$hora."', '".$especialidade."','".$observacoes."')";

....
```

o código principal é:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" >
<label>Data:</label>
<input type="date" name="data_marcacao"> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 

<label>Hora:</label>
<input type="time" name="hora_marcaçao">

....
$query = "SELECT especialidade FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       

?>

<form name="especialidades" method="post" action="">
<label for="cbEspecialidade">Selecione um Medico</label>
<select id="cbEspecialidade" name="cbEspecialidade">
<option>Selecione...</option>

<?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo '<option 
value="'.$prod['especialidade'].'">'.$prod['especialidade'].'</option>';
}
?>    
</select>

....

<div id="observacoes">
&nbsp &nbsp <label><b><font size=4>Observa&ccedil;&otilde;es:</font></b>
</label> <br>
&nbsp &nbsp  <textarea type="text" id="observacoes" value="" rows="3" cols="87" maxlength="50"> </textarea>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div id="botao">
  <input type="submit" name="botao_marcar" value="MARCAR CONSULTA" class=botaoEnviar /> 
</div>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que estou vendo no seu código, a select de Especialidade não tem o atributo name, além de que no PHP você está buscando com  um nome diferente que está no HTML.

Inclua o atributo name no select e chame no PHP com o mesmo valor, por exemplo "cbEspecialidade" como está no atributo ID

Comment: já editei o código a cima, para como o estou a usar agora mas continua sem dar... Não está a fazer ligação à base de dados e não consigo perceber porquê, se tirar a parte da informação da combobox fica a funcionar...

Comment: Há algumas coisas a se considerar, por exemplo: O banco possui a coluna 'especialidade'? Aceita o valor que está passando?

Comment: Já está resolvido.. Uma outra coisa, eu tenho um input type time, mas não é compativel com o atributo hora da tabela da base de dados... Há alguma forma de contornar isso?

Comment: Caso queira converter para timestamp, normalmente o campo já retorna no valor padrão para isso, tipo: $data = strtotime($_POST['data']);. Caso não esteja, você precisa fazer com que o valor do campo fique AAAA-MM-DD para usar esse comando. Caso queira converter esse timestamp em datetime, é só fazer $dt = date('Y/m/d h:i:s', $data);

Comment: Recomendo não usar o campo time, pois nem todos os navegadores tem suporte (leia-se microsoft)

Comment: Tenho uma outra forma de fazer isso, mas precisava de saber como faço uma query em que quero o que não está na base de dados, ou seja, eu tenho algumas horas marcadas na base de dados e quero uma query em que me apareçam todas as outras horas que ainda não estão marcadas.. Isto é possível?

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer uma tabela temporária de horas possíveis, e fazer um NOT IN das horas que está na sua tabela alvo, tipo: SELECT hora FROM #tabelatemporaria WHERE hora NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT hora FROM tabelaalvo)